# High Current Battery Power

Tags: power-supply, power, current

I'm looking to power about 10m of RGB LED strips (60 LEDs / meter) from a battery of some sort. Max current draw for the 10m run is 36A @ 5V.

My initial thought was to get a ~12V RC Car battery and run it through multiple DC/DC buck converters to get it down to 5V (probably get 8 rated at 5A or so) but I wanted to make sure I wasn't missing another, possibly cheaper, option. Runtime doesn't have to be super long... I'd be happy with anything beyond 20 minutes.

Also, note that 36A is absolute worst case scenario. Everything full white. In reality, it would probably average 1/2 - 1/4 of that... probably even less. But, obviously, I want to design for beyond max possible current to give some margin of error.

Battery needs to be rechargeable. Are there any other good (and hopefully cheap) options for providing that much power?

Comment: Getting that much current is easy. Getting it at 5V is not. Can you make the circuit work at some multiple of 3V7-4V2 instead?

Comment: Sadly, the LED strips (and the controller) require a regulated 5V. Why is it easier at those multiples?

Comment: Like I mentioned, I figured I'd have to run it through a regulator.

Comment: Because those are the multiples that Li-ion batteries come in.

Comment: Ahhh... figured. Sadly no. Gotta be 5V.

Comment: I can point you to SLVA001E, but you'll need to replace the BJT with a MOSFET in order to run multiple in parallel as well as change the circuit to run as push-pull instead of OC, and I don't know how much experience you have with that sort of thing.

Comment: Couldn't I just use a pre-built DC/DC buck converter (several of them actually)?

Comment: Minor variations in the converters will cause them to have slightly different voltages. Unless you're supplying each strip with a different converter, this can lead to cascade failure of all the converters. You want *one* control element, and multiple MOSFET switches in order to balance everything out.

Comment: Ahhh... yes, each converter will individually supply a sub-section of the total strip. each voltage section will be isolated from one another, except for ground of course.

Comment: Then that should work. Find yourself some Li-ion batteries with a high C rating and you're done.

Comment: 10 meters with 60 LEDs/meter is a total of 600 LEDs. Dividing your total current of 36A by 600 yields current per LED of 60mA. That seems a bit high for LEDs in a strip. Are you sure the current requirement is this high?

Comment: Thats exactly right. Each RGB element is rated at 20ma, there's 3 per LED, so 60mA each. That's exactly what they are rated at.

Answer (score 1):

Since you said cheap........
Any car repair place can get you a used car battery that has one weak cell. Sometimes just for the asking. Car batteries get 12V from 6 2V cells in series. So charging it at 13.8V yields a 10V output. A simple buck converter fed from this setup will get far beyond 20 minutes, even with full load demand. The buck converter will tolerate batteries that get worse for awhile as well.
If that requires too much weight or size for your application then consider feeding the buck converter from a 12V 12AH lead acid cell used to power UPS. Be careful to use an off the shelf charger, or provide some temperature sensing to limit charging current if you build your own charger. 
Your full load demand could make the battery's internal temperature rise so it will not tolerate as much charging current.

Comment: +1 for old car batteries, you won't get more electrons for your money. Easy to charge in the field if you arrived at the field in any sort of vehicle too ;)

Answer (score 0):

36 Amps 5V is about right for the 5V line of a scrap ATX off an old desktop computer.  Does it have to be battery?, the downconverters for 12V to 5V are usually much smaller; just a few amps each, and probably not best suited to parallel grouping.

White LED which I've tested all had a threshold near 2.6V and a normal operating voltage near 3.1 to 3.3V.  The reason for the 2.6V is the eV of a blue photon, so absolutely all should be about the same.  Those would work straight with 3-ish volts off the lithium batteries which you can get this year in a cylindrical case about 6cm long.  Mine are labelled "TR18650" which I think is the type and "5200mAh" which is lots, if it is not a lie from the marketing dept.  You'd want to make something with copper foil to bypass the 1 Amp rated wires on a cheap type of battery holder.  Supposing that you put four of those in parallel, and if necessary add more groups of four in parallel, that could give you as much current as you like at "about 3 to 4" volts, which is what I think your white LED need.

To charge that group, you'll want 4V not 5.